# Integration of Gnosis safe with external contracts

Tags: signature, gnosis-safe, multisignature, gnosis, gnosis-chain

Can anyone suggest how a safe created in gnosis UI be inherited with the explicit contract for multisign? I am aware of contract interactions that gnosis provides but the requirement is different. For instance, I have a smart contract where a function that requires multi-sign for execution. Gnosis does provide UI for creating safe but needs constraints on-chain as well.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to extend Safe features best way to do it would be writing a custom module

Comment: Can you suggest if there is any example available for it?

Comment: https://docs.gnosis-safe.io/contracts/modules-1 and https://github.com/safe-global/safe-modules